# What's the best way to generate or best place to find a consolidated list of Spring Framework dependencies?

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies

I'm looking for something like [this page that Spring provides for Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html) but for the various Framework versions.

Comment: Is spring boot bom good enough?

Comment: if using maven try with mvnw  dependency:tree

Comment: @Lesiak - no, Spring Boot is different. I am familiar with how to get this information for Boot.